# Visual Studio .NET has detected that the specified Web server is not running ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-io, vs-web-application-project

ok, I'm stumped.. yes, I've googled already and this time, it seems it is the first time that google failed me.

I have an ASP .Net Web Application project (acquired from a predecessor who loves brute algorithms and redundancies in his codes) and was trying to open it in a VS .NET 2003 where it was developed (well, actually not on the same machine where it was developed.) The project is a part of a larger solution composed of other VB projects. When I first opened the inherited solution some era ago, I found that an error prevented me from opening the said web project... I just ignore it then because the project wasn't that important before. Now that the project needs to be maintained, I think it's time for me to get my hands dirty with it.

This is my first time opening a web application project so I expected that there will be something wrong:
**Visual Studio .NET has detected that the specified Web server is not running ASP.NET 1.1. You will be unable to run ASP.NET Web applications or services.**

Right. With the use of a trusty Google, I have tried my efforts on the following (but as I have said, this time, she failed me):

1. Uninstall .NET framework 1.1
2. Reinstall .Net framework 1.1
3. Followed [KB 306005](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306005) which says about: `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`
4. Tried the switches `-u`, `-ua`, `-c` and `-enable` for `aspnet_regiis.exe`
5. Restarted IIS
6. Deleted the folder for framework 1.0

rebooting and/or retrying between the items above, but I still get the same error.

There's another thing I tried, changing the path of the project in the .sln file using notepad. I changed the word "localhost" to my IP address but it produced another error saying that it can't open the project and that the web does not exist.. it asked me to try another file share path. No joy there.

I noticed that by accessing the address `http://192.168.2.138/MyWebProject/main.aspx` in a browser, the web page looks ok (that's my IP, btw). But the `http://localhost/MyWebProject/main.aspx` doesn't work and gives the message: No web site is configured at this address.

I'm using XPProSP3 with updates of Oct 2010; I have .Net Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1 installed together with 1.1; Latest SP for 1.1 is KB979906.

I think that I'm just missing something that needs to do before making a ASP .Net web project.. :D

I like to open the project in my VS but I'm stumped. How can I open it?

Comment: +1 for detail and all the things you've tried already. good first question. Welcome to SO

Comment: just an update: I tried creating my first web app but the same error greeted me. So my problem now is no longer opening this particular file, I bet any other web app project won't be opened in my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew I am missing something above. I was able to pass through the error today by doing the following:

1. Uninstalled IIS 5.1
2. Reboot
3. Reinstalled IIS 5.1
4. Do `aspnet_regiis -i` of the installed version 1.1.4322
5. Reboot
6. Tried making a new ASP.NET web app and I was able to make one.
7. Tried opening the file in my post above and it gave a new error:
   **Unable to get the project file from the web server.**

Well, that's a new error for me, another story and I think there's no point of continuing this thread because the title says so. I have to move on and continue to discover how to open this file. ;)

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

Change the webside address to nothing or add localhost to it (in site properties in IIS). Alternatively in project properties switch to builtin asp.net webserver.

If you can visit the site on one URL, but not another (and both point to the same computer) then most likely it is a problem with the web server configuration. Both hostnames are not bound to that solution/folder. It CAN be a firewall issue. Try temporarily disabling the local firewall.

The access logs from IIS and the Event Log are valuable resources in troubleshooting such issues.

Comment: I'm trying to find some images to guide you in setting up the integrated web server, but can't find it. This may have been a feature that came in later VS versions.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. Although a bit risky, I tried disabling the windows firewall, and tried opening the project after reboot but I still had no joy there (I returned the firewall now.)

Comment: I still am figuring out where exactly the website address of the site properties in IIS.. (I told myself that I should make my very first ASP .Net web project as a prerequisite for this issue.. so that I'd be smarter, at least. :D)  The alternative way didn't work though.. because the project, although listed in the solution explorer, is shown as unavailable.. so VS tells me that "there are no property pages in the selection."

Comment: yeah, I forgot.. setting the firewall off doesn't make the url with localhost above to work.

Comment: I was trying to mark this answer as useful but I believe I still can't do it yet.. (I should have 15 reputations). Thanks for the help.